# Facebook search with Selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, element, searchbar

I am a beginner to Selenium and trying to search post with some keywords through Facebook search bar.

I am unable to locate Facebook search bar and put some text in it. I can make another request just like this 'https://www.facebook.com/search/posts/?q=keyword' but I want to search using Facebook search bar.

Can anybody help?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.facebook.com")
username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("pass")
submit = browser.find_element_by_id("loginbutton")
username.send_keys("")
password.send_keys("")
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```py
...
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#bluebarRoot > div > div > div > div._2t-e > div._4kny._50tm > div > form > div > div > input[name='q']")
search.send_keys('foo') # search for 'foo'
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#bluebarRoot > div > div > div > div._2t-e > div._4kny._50tm > div > form > button')
submit.click()
```

Comment: its working but not working for button 
its inputting text but not clicking.